# Cannot run iOS Extension with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I added a Device Monitoring extension and I did Debug -> Attach to Process
but each time I run it I get a

```
Cannot create a FlutterEngine instance in debug mode without Flutter tooling or Xcode.
To launch in debug mode in iOS 14+, run flutter run from Flutter tools, run from an IDE with a Flutter IDE plugin or run the iOS project from Xcode.
```

I select my Flutter app when it prompts me too.
The weird thing is I got it to work one time, so I am not sure why. this is happening